# Is the text that the innerHTML property replaces actually read by a browser?

Tags: javascript, html

In this example does the browser skip over the text "This text will not be printed" since there is a script that will replace it?

```
<script>
function produceSongLyric(){
    var msg= 'Spent my money<br />Took my car<br/>Started telling her friends she\'s gonna be a star';
    return msg;
}

</script>

<span id="mySpanName" style="color:red">This text will not be printed</span>

<script>
    document.getElementById("mySpanName").innerHTML=produceSongLyric();
</script>
```

EDIT: Can't you paste into jsfiddle?

Comment: Use Right-click / Paste to paste into jsFiddle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the browser won't skip it.

It has no way of knowing that it will be replaced until the script executes.

Answer (score 0):

Nope... it finds it.  See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hCQ5d/)

Comment: @Nupul wow. din't even see your post (answer->click submit->continue working on something else), but as for "exact same thing", it's not.  Mine acts as a break point so you can see "This text will not be printed" actually printed on the page.

Comment: Aaah...mine does too...I can see it :)

Comment: @Nupul fascinating... what browser are you viewing it with (I'm using chrome 13)

Answer (score 0):

Here have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/nupul/gtN5w/ You will see the text get printed. It's just that the script get's executed and 60hz refresh frequency of the monitor probably prevents you from seeing it ;)

Answer (score 0):

No, the browser won't skip it. Keep in mind that if something of strange but possible forces the web server to send not all the document in one network packet, but takes a little time to send the last script element, probably the browser wants to show it!

I suggest you to make that span invisible by setting a `display:none;` CSS property, removing it dinamically at the end of the script.

Note also that a document.getElementById should be used only after the window load event is been thrown.